# Dealloc not getting called?

Tags: ios, memory, dealloc

This is how I switch views in my app:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(frame);
    ViewController *view2 = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    view2.view.frame = frame;
    [self.view.superview addSubview:view2.view];    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
                         view2.view.frame = frame;
                         frame.origin.x -= frame.size.width;
                         self.view.frame = frame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
```

The problem is, is that my dealloc is not getting called. Any ideas why and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you set `self.view = NULL;` in your completion? Oh, and is it safe for me to assume you're using ARC?

Comment: I am not using ARC. If I set self.view = NULL, the dealloc still gets not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code in a view controller (it looks like it is)?  If so, it makes sense removing your view would not cause the view controller itself to be released - someone else is retaining that.  It's the same thing that happens during a memory warning when your view is unloaded, but not your view controller...

Basically, what dealloc are you expecting to be called?

Comment: yep, ViewController is a view controller. Pretty much I want the self.view View Controller NOT ViewController to be released in the completion handler of the code above. How would I do that?

Comment: I ended up fixing this, I did a workaround that worked for me.

Comment: Just on a side note, if you wanted the view to be released you'd probably have to call self.view = nil also since the VC is retaining it...  but I have to say that what you are trying to do sounds very odd and may cause the system to behave oddly.

Comment: It actually does not behave oddly at all. I just created the next view using a IBOutlet in the first view and then creating the next view in Interface Builder. It actually works quite well!

Comment: I understand, that technique is pretty common.  I was thinking it was the main VC view you were trying to destroy (which I still think could have repercussions you may not be considering).

Comment: Sorry to bring back this thread but this still seems to be an issue. With that code, how could I fully release the viewcontroller so the dealloc gets called also? This is causing for many things to leak in my app!

Comment: Actually in the completion handler I am doing [self release]; is that ok?

Comment: Generally calling [self release] is a bad idea.  It can be done but it's really dangerous.  Is there some reason you cannot use ARC?  There is no way I would do any new iOS development now without using ARC.

Comment: My app just already has so much code, it would take ages to convert it. Plus I am just not too familiar with it. When you say bad idea, do you mean crashes? I tried it and there's no crashes but at least my dealloc gets called

Comment: Crashes or memory leaks...  You should at least run the ARC converter on a copy of your code to see what would be involved.

Comment: For the moment though, if it is not crashing or producing any leaks, I guess it is ok right?

Comment: I can't really answer that, only you can.  If you are comfortable with it let it be for the moment.